# Relationship between complex refractive index and complex conductivity in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, electrical-resistance, refraction, maxwell-equations, complex-numbers

In my field (time-resolved spectroscopes of semiconductors), people use this equation like it was trivial and never cited a source or provide derivation:

$$\tilde\sigma = i\omega\varepsilon_0 (1-\tilde{n}^2)$$

I'm trying to derive this equation from the very basic:

**Everything below is complex!**

From Maxwell equation:
$$\nabla\times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} $$
Apply $\nabla\times$ on both sides
$$\nabla\times (\nabla\times E) =\nabla\times(-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}) $$
Rearrange:
$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot E)-\nabla^2E =-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\times B) $$

Using the definitions:
$$B\equiv\mu_0\mu_r H$$
$$D\equiv\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r E $$

and Ampère's circuital law:
$$\nabla\times H = j+\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$$

We get:
$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot E)-\nabla^2E =-\mu_0\mu_r\frac{\partial}{\partial t}j-\mu_0\mu_r\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E $$

Assuming the medium is **homogeneous, isotropic, and neutral**:
$$\rho=\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\nabla\cdot E=0$$

$$-\nabla^2E =-\mu_0\mu_r\frac{\partial}{\partial t}j-\mu_0\mu_r\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E $$

Using the definition:
$$j\equiv\sigma E$$

$$\mu_0\mu_r\sigma\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E+\mu_0\mu_r\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E-\nabla^2E =0$$

Somehow solving the last equation will get:
$$n^2=\mu_r\varepsilon_r+\frac{i\mu_r\sigma}{\varepsilon_r\omega}$$

I'm having trouble solving the last equation and get the final relationship.

Comment: Use Fourier transform - the relationship that you are trying to derive is in frequency space.

Answer (score 0):

Let as employ Fourier transform:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)=\int d^3\mathbf{k}\int d\omega \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{k},\omega)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}-i\omega t}
$$
Substituting this into the equation
$$\mu_0\mu_r\sigma\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E+\mu_0\mu_r\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E-\nabla^2 =0,$$
we obtain
$$
\int d^3\mathbf{k}\int d\omega \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{k},\omega)e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}-i\omega t}\left[-i\omega\mu_0\mu_r\sigma -\mu_0\mu_r\epsilon_0\epsilon_r\omega^2+k^2\right]=0
$$
Since the field can be arbitrary, for the identity to always hold we need $$
-i\omega\mu_0\mu_r\sigma -\mu_0\mu_r\epsilon_0\epsilon_r\omega^2+k^2=0.$$
In case of uniform fields, $k=0$, we have
$$
-i\omega\sigma=\epsilon_0\epsilon_r\omega^2\Leftrightarrow \sigma=i\omega\epsilon\epsilon_r
$$

Comment: your answer did not arrive the target equation in the question, the constant term is missing