# Is $n=\sqrt{\mu_r\varepsilon_r}$ always true? even with complex value?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, refraction

I have trouble deriving a supposedly "well-known" equation used in condensed matter physics:
$$n^2=\mu_r\varepsilon_r+\frac{i\mu_r\sigma}{\varepsilon_r\omega}$$

I'm sure that $n$ and $\sigma$ are complex, and this equition is obtained by solving
$$\mu_0\mu_r\sigma\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E+\mu_0\mu_r\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}E-\nabla^2E =0$$

which is linked to [my other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/752373/relationship-between-complex-refractive-index-and-complex-conductivity-in-conden)

However this seem to contradict with the well-known relationship:

$$n=\sqrt{\mu_r\varepsilon_r}$$

Comment: You should provide references to the "well known" formula

Comment: In such cases you have to go back to Maxwell's equs and reason it through. Among other things you will need to state a definition of $n$. I am guessing it is $\omega/k = c/n$ where $k$ can be complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to introduce a complex value for epsilon. You can understand that by using the Maxwell-Ampère equation. (I might be wrong, I am just a student)

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).